Why does my getAppName function only return the package name for some apps instead of their real name? (android studio)
I'm working on an Android app (screen time, kotlin) where I need to display the names of the apps along with their usage statistics. To achieve this, I've implemented a getAppName function in my code to retrieve the app names using their package names. However, I've noticed that for some apps, the function only returns the package name instead of their actual names.
private fun getAppName(packageName: String): String {
    return try {
        val pm: PackageManager = context?.packageManager!!
        val applicationInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0)
        pm.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo).toString()
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        packageName // Fallback to package name if app name is not found
    }
}

And here's how I'm using it:
val appName = getAppName(usageStat.packageName)

For some apps(Gallery,settings,camera), this works fine and I'm able to display their names correctly. However, for most of the apps, it only returns their package names.
Is there something wrong with my implementation of getAppName? Or is there a limitation or special case that I'm not aware of? I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to ensure that I can consistently retrieve the names of all apps.
private fun getUsageStats(): Map<String, Long> {
val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
val beginTime = endTime - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 // 1 day

val usageStatsList = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, beginTime, endTime)

val appTimeMap = mutableMapOf<String, Long>()

// Aggregate the time spent in each app
for (usageStat in usageStatsList) {
    val totalTimeInForeground = usageStat.totalTimeInForeground
    if (totalTimeInForeground > 0) { // Check if the app has been used
        val appName = getAppName(usageStat.packageName)
        appTimeMap[appName] = appTimeMap.getOrDefault(appName, 0) + totalTimeInForeground
    }
}

return appTimeMap
}

Thank you in advance for your help!

wouldnt you be getting the package name because that is what you have returning if the NameNotFoundException is thrown?

Where are you getting the package name from

yeah, but how can I really get the real app name instead of the package name? Cuz I've installed other screen time app, they all can retrieve the name of the app in my phone.

Show where you are getting your package names from

Isn't it in the getAppName function showed above?

getApplicationInfo

that does not show where it comes from just that you pass something in

package name is not the app name. Where does usageStat.packageName come from

is this what you mean?

Do you wanna me to provide the whole github file for you to try?

I would cross reference all the package names you get with the usage statistics query with package manager's queryIntentActivities to see if the match.

https://github.com/mrlegend4/BottomNav

this is the original github file

This question could be greatly simplified because it has a bunch of indirection about stuff you are doing specifically in this function that is irrelevant to your problem. It returns a package name because that’s the fallback you put in your code when it throws NameNotFoundException, so the real question is just how to get the actual name of a package from PackageManager without it throwing NameNotFoundException. All the extra paragraphs and sample code are irrelevant.

The reason I mention it is because you might be causing fewer people to attempt to answer your question. When they see the title saying it returns a package name instead of the real name, someone who knows how to do this might not even click it because they’ve never seen the indirect problem you’re describing in the title. And some who do click it and see the wall of irrelevant code might decide not to bother reading all that and just move on.

Yeah, sorry for that. But can I know how to avoid package manager from throwing NameNotFoundException?
